# Creating a JScrollPane inside a CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, cardlayout

My program has two columns as you can see on the screenshot.

[image]

I used CardLayout for the right columns.

Now I have a panel that is dynamic, mean I can add a row(which has text field) with every single click. And I want to make it scrollable so that I can add unlimited rows.

I added that dynamic JPanel to a JScrollPane. Then added that JScrollPane to the main CardLayout panel. But it's not working.

Here's the code:

```
frmCgpaCalculator = new JPanel();
frmCgpaCalculator.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
frmCgpaCalculator.setBounds(100, 100, 835, 1600);
frmCgpaCalculator.setLayout(null);
frmCgpaCalculator.setVisible(true);
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(frmCgpaCalculator);
scrollPane.setBounds(40, 150, 480, 300);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: Don't use a null layout!!! A JScrollPane will not work with a panel that uses a null layout.

Comment: The absolute layout panel is inside the JScrollPane, not outside. I tried removing frmCgpaCalculator.setLayout(null); but it made everything non-responsive.

Comment: `The absolute layout panel is inside the JScrollPane` Exactly. Scrollbars  appear when the preferred size of the component added to the scrollpane is greater than the size of the scrollpane. Because you are using a null layout the preferred size is never calculated (since this is the job of the layout manager), so the size is (0, 0) and there is never any need for the scrollbars to be used.

Comment: How to fix it then? This is my first project on GUI swing

Comment: Maybe use a `GridBagLayout`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and examples.